# How to create a coordinate grid in Exam class in multicol with the number at top

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol

I'm trying to figure out how to change the following.  When I write the following code, I get the second question label at the bottom of the image.  If I add in a // after the second question before the first to get the grid on another line, I get the error that there is no line to end here, understandably.  Here is the MWE.

```
    \documentclass{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol,tikz}

    \begin{document}
    Instructions here.
    \begin{questions}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \question
    First Question

    \columnbreak

    \question
    \begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=0.35, yscale=0.35] %Change size of grid
    \draw[help lines] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (-10,0) -- (10,0); %x-axis
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (0,-10) -- (0,10); %y-axis
    \node[right] at (10,0) {$x$}; %label x-axis
    \node[above] at (0,10) {$y$}; %label y-axis
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{questions}
    
    \end{document}
```

I can work around this by adding in text like the following, but it's not an ideal solution.

```
    \documentclass{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol,tikz}

    \begin{document}
    Instructions here.
    \begin{questions}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \question
    First Question

    \columnbreak

    \question
    Here's some text\\
    \begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=0.35, yscale=0.35] %Change size of grid
    \draw[help lines] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (-10,0) -- (10,0); %x-axis
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (0,-10) -- (0,10); %y-axis
    \node[right] at (10,0) {$x$}; %label x-axis
    \node[above] at (0,10) {$y$}; %label y-axis
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{questions}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I'm sure there is some property I need to change if it is possible.  I just couldn't find it in the documentation of multicol or TikZ.  Any help if greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want any text, you can add a phantom text: `\question \vphantom{H}\\ ` for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the `baseline` reference point for the `tikzpicture`

```
\documentclass{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol,tikz}

    \begin{document}
    Instructions here.
    \begin{questions}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \question
    First Question

    \columnbreak

    \question
    \begin{tikzpicture} [xscale=0.35, yscale=0.35, baseline=(current bounding box.north)] %Change size of grid
    \draw[help lines] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (-10,0) -- (10,0); %x-axis
    \draw[<->, ultra thick] (0,-10) -- (0,10); %y-axis
    \node[right] at (10,0) {$x$}; %label x-axis
    \node[above] at (0,10) {$y$}; %label y-axis
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{questions}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks so much!